# Make apache(angular) javascript root files private

Tags: angular, apache, httpd.conf

I have deployed an Angular 13 project to an Apache server, running on Rocky Linux 9.
Everything works as intended, except the fact that any user can read the js and css files found at the root of the directory.

[image]

I tried several options inside the apache configuration file :

```
    # deny access to js and css root files
    <LocationMatch "^.{1,}.js|.css$">
       Require all denied 
    </LocationMatch>
```

also:

```
    #Forbid access to root js files
     <Files ~ "\.js$">
       Order allow,deny
       Deny from all
     </Files>
```

Both options block access to js files, but for everyone. The website is useless with these options.
I am also using the option that blocks directory browsing, that works perfect:

```
     Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
```

Do you have any idea on how I could stop the public access to root js and css files, while keeping the website working ?

Comment: If the public needs to run your angular app, it needs to be able to read it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Olaf. Leaving js root files public is the only way to do it ?Doesn't this pose a security problem ?

Comment: Only if you put sensitive data into your code. If it's being executed in a browser, how else would it get to the browser if it wasn't available?